# How to reproduce ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT with FileAPI?

Tags: winapi

I have several instances of program. Each application uses different file and write some information to that file.
In general it works fine for a long period of time, but in one case I found out that all of the instances failed to write to their files at the same time with this error code: **ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT (0x13)**.
Must note that I have no idea what happened at this time on a server running the programs.
Here is code snippet from the program:

```
Handle myHandle = CreateFile(fileName,
    GENERIC_ALL,
    FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    NULL,
    CREATE_NEW,
    FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
    NULL);

DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
unsigned char buffer[bufferSize];

// Code that fills the buffer

if (!WriteFile(myHandle, buffer, bufferSize, &dwBytesWritten, NULL))
{
    // Log GetLastError() result
}
```

I am trying to figure out why this could happen, and how can I reproduce it at all?
What kind of manipulation do I have to do on the file or folder to get ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT (0x13) error code?

Comment: instead call and log `GetLastError()` do this with `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` - will be more informative. 2 different status - `STATUS_MEDIA_WRITE_PROTECTED` and `STATUS_TOO_LATE` (*A write operation was attempted to a volume after it was dismounted.*) mapped to the `ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT`. may be you really got `STATUS_TOO_LATE` error

Answer (score 2):

> What kind of manipulation do I have to do on the file or folder to get ERROR_WRITE_PROTECT (0x13) error code?

Possibly eject floppy drive, flip that switch, and insert it back? May sound weird the days computer do not have floppies, but there should be floppy drive emulators, and VMs such as VMWare are able to emulate floppies, so it could be possible.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, it's pretty hard to do it with floppy simulation, which in my case doesn't exist for sure, but, I tried to simulate it with "network drive". I disconnected the "network drive" while writting to the file, but I got ERROR_UNEXP_NET_ERR 59 (0x3B)

Comment: I think that it is expected that with network drive behavior is not the same. Possibly the closest thing you can do is to eject flash drive in proper moment (taking into account the comment the comment about `STATUS_TOO_LATE` mapping to this error).